# EclipseME - Network permission

Tags: java-me, permissions, eclipseme

I have a j2me project that works fine in netbeans.
Since i need to develop a android version i have moved to Eclipse.
I have downloaded Eclipse ME and imported the j2me project.

Im able to run the app, but i dont get "Is It Ok To Use Airtime" permission.
I checked the jad and all the permissions are there. Emulator is "Sun Java(TM) Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2_01 for CLDC".

Any idea why the internet connection is not working?

Answer (score 2):

Anyway i found the source of my problem. As i expected it had something to do with the settings. In WTK (install_folder/bin/ktoolbar.exe) there is section "Security" under Edit/Preferences. I set "Security domain" to "manufacturer". Saved and exit. In Eclipse i right click the project and under either "Run as" or "Debug as" i selected "... Configuration". Under "Emulator" tab the security domain property had to match up (manufacturer). After that all worked perfectly. Since first part of the problem was hinted in one of bhakki links im awarding bhakki for his time and effort put into my problem.