# j2me 'Is it ok to use airtime"

Tags: eclipse, java-me, emulation

i'm attempting an *http connection* through emulator it always asks **'Is it ok to use airtime'** and results nothing for both accept and reject cases. Is there any configuration problem ?.

Moreover i'm using ***eclipse pulsar*** in ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not configuration problem. You are communicating the server through `HttpConnection`. Your application not signed. So whenever connection made it showing the such question. See this article [“OK to use Airtime” on Mobile Emulators.](http://www.mernin.com/blog/2006/11/ok-to-use-airtime-on-mobile-emulators/) Follow the mentioned configuration on that article and avoid this question on the emulator. But if you running on the mobile means you should [sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425627/how-to-skip-the-questions-when-using-fileconnection/6435401#6435401) the midlet.

Comment: bhakki how to do that configuration in ubuntu. As i mentioned i'm run through eclipse pulsar

Comment: found the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388735/eclipseme-network-permission

Comment: @Paniyar: Also see this article [jar signing](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JAR_Signing)